# Is mockito spiedInstance broken (compared to spy) or is the doc misleading?

Tags: mockito

The current mockito documentation page for MockSettings includes this

```
Foo foo = mock(Foo.class, withSettings().spiedInstance(fooInstance));
//Below does exactly the same:
Foo foo = spy(fooInstance);
```

However the following quick test gives different results:

```
HashMap<String, String> realMap = new HashMap();
realMap.put("city", "Boston");

HashMap spy1 = spy(realMap);
HashMap spy2 = mock(HashMap.class, withSettings().spiedInstance(realMap));

System.out.println("spy1 city: " + spy1.get("city"));
System.out.println("spy2 city: " + spy2.get("city"));
```

Output:

```
spy1 city: Boston
spy2 city: null
```

Am I misunderstanding something, or is that latter usage broken (didn't see anything on the mockito project issues page...)?  As a side note, my goal is to do some mocking on unfamiliar legacy code and was hoping to achieve a spy with verbose logging by something like

```
mock(Foo.class, withSettings.spiedInstance(f).verboseLogging())
```

any alternatives staying with mockito as my toolset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice catch. This is a bug or at least the javadoc is wrong.

If you look at [`Mockito.spy`](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/master/src/org/mockito/Mockito.java#L1337-L1341) source code:

```
public static <T> T spy(T object) {
    return MOCKITO_CORE.mock((Class<T>) object.getClass(), withSettings()
            .spiedInstance(object)
            .defaultAnswer(CALLS_REAL_METHODS));
}
```

you could easily fix your problem :

```
Foo foo = mock(Foo.class, withSettings()
           .spiedInstance(fooInstance))
           .defaultAnswer(CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
//Below does exactly the same:
Foo foo = spy(fooInstance);
```